# CSS and fixed background not work

Tags: html, css

I have content with an image on the right.

[image: Image 1]

My image have 950 px for height. I wish it to move at the same time as the scrooll.

If I add this property " **background-attachment: fixed;** ", it works but the image is zoomed, I do not want :(

[image: Image 2]

Can you help me ? **This is Fiddle :**

```css
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif
}

/*  --------------------------------------------------
/*  Text-transform
/*  --------------------------------------------------
*/
.content-image-left-right {
    background-color: #fff
}

.content-image-left-right h2 {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .4rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.content-image-left-right p {
    max-width: 450px;
    color: #605e5e;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: justify
}

.content-image-left-right .cover {
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url(https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/422842background3.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div class='content-image-left-right'>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>
                        Gérer
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Grâce à notre solution <strong>complète et assistée</strong>, Dometech vous permet <strong>une gestion simple et centralisée de tous vos biens</strong>.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col cover background-3">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: provide a working fiddle

Comment: yes @DavidHope ..

Comment: Remove the height property from css this will work fine

Comment: It's OK now for Fiddle :)

Comment: how do you want it to be displayed? the whole image is reduce to the exact width and height of the div?

Comment: @Gaylord.P I edited my answer.. look at it again..

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif
}

/*  --------------------------------------------------
/*  Text-transform
/*  --------------------------------------------------
*/
.content-image-left-right {
    background-color: #fff
}

.content-image-left-right h2 {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .4rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.content-image-left-right p {
    max-width: 450px;
    color: #605e5e;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: justify
}

.content-image-left-right .cover {
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url(https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/422842background3.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 550px 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div class='content-image-left-right'>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>
                        Gérer
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Grâce à notre solution <strong>complète et assistée</strong>, Dometech vous permet <strong>une gestion simple et centralisée de tous vos biens</strong>.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col cover background-3">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It does not work in my situation :/ I post Fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `backgound-size: cover` and replace with size of image [background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for example `background-size: 550px 300px` where first value is width second height